# Redirect some http requests from one IIS to a another IIS on the network

Tags: iis, proxy, http, windows-sbs-2011

We have a network exposed externally through a static IP address. Our main SBS 2011 server hosts the remote/mail website (remote.company.net), while another IIS server on the network hosts our clients website (clients.company.net).

However, I can't make client.company.net http requests to bounce from the SBS to the other IIS, where that website is actually hosted.

Could you please help me set this up? 
Thanks

Comment: Is client.company.net not publicly visible? Do you mean that you want requests from the public internet to be routed through remote.company.net? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: client.company.net is not publicly visible. We have only one external IP, so all http requests come to the Windows Business Server. But the clients website is on a different server... so I need to redirect/route requests to the right server.

Comment: "But the clients website is on a different server." as in it's on client.company.net ?

Comment: Kev, forget the names of the websites.. basically, we have two websites, each in a different IIS on the network.. But we have only one external IP, hence our need to set up a proxy/redirect..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Application Request Routing... it is the only way to proxy requests the way you are describing.  It provides request routing logic: http://www.iis.net/download/applicationrequestrouting
-Chris